# Does the Shannon Entropy always exist (even for infinite distributions)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, divergent-series, entropy

Let $p : \mathbb{N} \to [0, 1]$ be a probability distribution over the naturals.

The Shannon Entropy is:

$$H = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)\log_2 p(n)$$

Does this series always converge?

---

I tried a little to attack this problem but it's been some time since I evaluate series. My attempt:

We known that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) = 1$, therefore it must be the case that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} p(n) = 0$, and since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\log_2 x = 0$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists only a finite amount of terms greater than $\varepsilon$. The problem is that I can't conclude anything from this, because there are several series in which the terms go to zero but it still diverges.

Answer (score 3):

This series does not always converge. First of all, note that the following series converges:
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \lceil 2^i/i^2\rceil \cdot 2^{-i}.$$
This is because $\lceil 2^i/i^2\rceil \le 2^i/i^2 + 1 =  O(2^{i}/i^2)$ as $i\to \infty$. Hence there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \lceil 2^i/i^2\rceil \cdot c2^{-i} = 1.$$

So, consider a probablity distribution over $\mathbb{N}$ in which for every $i\ge 1$ there are exactly $\lceil 2^i/i^2\rceil$ probablities which are equal $c2^{-i}$.  Shannon entropy diverges for such distribution:
\begin{align*}
H = \sum\limits_{i\ge 1} \lceil 2^i/i^2 \rceil \cdot c 2^{-i} \log_2(2^i/c) 
 &\ge \sum\limits_{i\ge \max\{1,\, 2\log_2(c)\}} \lceil 2^i/i^2 \rceil \cdot c 2^{-i} \log_2(2^i/c) \\
&\ge \sum\limits_{i\ge \max\{1,\, 2\log_2(c)\}}  2^i/i^2 \cdot c 2^{-i} \log_2(2^i/2^{i/2})\\
&= \sum\limits_{i\ge \max\{1,\, 2\log_2(c)\}}  \frac{c}{2i}.
\end{align*}

Comment: You've misapplied the definition.  The correct sum for the entropy would be
$$
H = \sum\limits_{i\ge 1} \lceil 2^i/i^2 \rceil \cdot c 2^{-i} \log_2\left( \lceil 2^i/i^2 \rceil \cdot c 2^{-i}\right)
$$
which does converge

Comment: Hmm, $\lceil 2^i/i^2\rceil$ is the number of $n$ such that $p(n) = c 2^{-i}$ so it should not be put into logarithm

Comment: note that entropy is given by $\Bbb E(-\ln(P(X)))$ as opposed to $\Bbb E(-\ln(X))$

Comment: @SashaKozachinskiy In the last part of your solution, I think your first inequality is unjustified. The only thing I could write was $ \sum \limits_{i \ge 1} \lceil 2^i/i^2 \rceil \cdot c 2^{-i} \log_2(2^i/c) 
 \leq \sum\limits_{i\ge \max\{1,\, \log_2(c)\}} \lceil 2^i/i^2 \rceil \cdot c 2^{-i} \log_2(2^i/c)$ because truncating the sum on the RHS throws out the negative terms. Please check this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Define $p$ by

$$ p(n) = \frac{c}{(n+2)\log^2(n+2)}, $$

where $c$ is the normalizing constant. Then it follows that $-p(n)\log p(n) \sim c/n \log n$ as $n\to\infty$ and hence $H(p) = \infty$ by the limit comparison test.